# looking for help to start a video to play at specific day and time otherwise play 2nd video using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for help to start a video to play at specific day and time otherwise play 2nd video will play using JavaScript and yes it should be without refresh the file

Comment: context? can u please share code you've tried? the error/s? the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

first thing pops into my head is to use setInterval() to check the current date&time after a specific interval/period of time (like every second/minute).